# Documenting Python to MS Word readable format

Tags: python, ms-word, doc

I'm trying to produce a post-dev "interface control document" for a not particularly well documented, smallish Python codebase. To fit into an in-place document schema it needs to be delivered as a flat Word document. It needs to be mostly extracted from the code.

So far my only candidate is doxygen's .rtf capability. And doxygen is sort of so-so with Python. And so-so with rtf. So. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python community is a strong supporter of the [ReST](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) format.  I've grown to love it after having to deal with massive word documents. [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) is a great documentation tool that can be used document your projects, and is used by http://readthedocs.org, although it may be a little much to setup for a small project.

So I would recommend writing in [ReST](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) and seeing how it converts to word, via [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

And really, [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) supports converting the following formats to word and many other formats, so you have a lot of formats you can write documentation in if you want to avoid writing in word:

- markdown
- reStructuredText (ReST)
- textile
- HTML
- DocBook
- LaTeX